# Stuck In Infinite While Loop (with switch statement)

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement

I haven't used Java in a while and am having a simple yet frustrating error. My code is something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String input = "";
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while(input != "Q"){
        input = in.readLine().toUpperCase();
        switch(input){
            default: break;
            case "A": //do stuff break;
            case "B": //do stuff break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Out of the loop!"); //never reaches this statement
}
```

I ran the eclipse debugger and it clearly shows the input variable being changed to "Q" when entered by the user, but the while loop keeps restarting.

Comment: Do you want to `break` out of the switch statement or do you want to jump to the end of the `while` loop? Because in the latter case, the `break` targets the `switch` and needs an explicit label to work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change while to

```
while(!input.equals("Q"))
```

compare string with `equals()` not with `==`

In addition use a `break;` after each case otherwise you would have a [fallthrough](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: .equals()! of course. thank you so much, ive been doing a lot of python recently and it's messing me up lol

Comment: If you know that question is duplicate you should vote it as such instead of answering it. We don't really need thousand-th answer about that subject. I know that new users may not know it but you already have 5k, so use your *closing/flagging* privilege.

Comment: @Pshemo  I keep that in mind  next time

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the strings using `equals` (values comparison) instead of `==` (which compares references):

```
while (!"Q".equals(input))
```

**Hint:** if you call `equals` on the string literal, it will not fail with `NullPointerException` in case `input` is, by some chance, `null` - in such case it would just return `false`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `input.equals("Q")` when comparing strings.